# Autohotkey. Increasing send key iterations

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to be able to send the TAB key an ever-increasing number of times as part of a loop. Essentially, I want to cycle through some parts of the webpage with tab, get to where I need to be, do some stuff, and start over. But each time I start over, I will have added two additional items that need to be cycled through. So I need a loop that looks like this:

```
n = 1
Start the loop
Send {Tab n}
DO STUFF
n += 2
Repeat the loop with n updated
```

I'm not sure if I can use variables like that, however. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
n = 1
Loop ; Start the loop
{
    Msgbox % "n = " n
    SendInput, % "{Tab " n "}"
    ; DO STUFF
    n += 2
} ; Repeat the loop with n updated
```

You can check the documentation here: [Loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm)

Comment: You're not referencing the variable `n`. Use `SendInput, % "{Tab " n "}"` or `SendInput, {Tab %n%}` in legacy (please don't use legacy). Also switch to using [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail). And [here's](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key) the documentation link for the repeating key syntax in a `Send` -command.